# Is there any condition to check whether the given system of linear equations with 3 variable have unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Recently I was studying Matrices and Determinants and while solving problems for no solution, unique solutions using Gauss-Jordan Elimination,  I thought is there any method or condition to check whether the given system of 3 linear equations in which each has 3 variables (x,y,z) have a Unique or Infinite or No Solution like as we use in the two-variable linear equation? So that we can solve problems alternatively to row reduction.

Comment: There is something that can determine whether there is a unique solution or not.  If there is not one, you will have to take further steps to determine whether you have a parameterized solution or no solution at all.  To help you, please provide context ([here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) is _How to ask a good question_).

Comment: At least If there is a pattern then it would be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an equation of two variables is representative of a line, an equation of three variables is representative of a plane.  A planar system of three equations where the planes are pairwise nonparallel will have a unique solution iff the triple scalar product of the normals is nonzero.  A good idea would be to query "[intersection of three planes](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=intersection+of+three+planes)" for better understanding.

For example:

> Determine whether the following system of equations has a unique solution: \begin{cases}
> x-y+z+2=0\\
> 2x-y-2z+9=0\\
> 3x+y-z+2=0
> \end{cases}
> Define $\vec{n_1}=(1,-1,1)$, $\vec{n_2}=(2,-1,-2)$, and $\vec{n_3}=(3,1,-1)$.  The system will have a unique solution if $\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}\times\vec{n_3}\neq0$.
> \begin{align*}
> \vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}\times\vec{n_3}&=(1,-1,1)\cdot(2,-1,-2)\times(3,1,-1)\\
> &=(1,-1,1)\cdot(3,-4,5)\\
> &=12\neq0
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, the system of equations has a unique solution.